# map List<string[]> with fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I'd like to map a List < string [] > with fluent nhibernate, that is a List containing string arrays. The strings needs to be of the type Text for the ms sql db.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: what table schema do you want? `ListTable (foreignkey, PositionInList, PositionInArray, text)` or `ListTable (foreignkey, PositionInList); StringTable(foreignkeyToListTable, PositionInArray, text)` or `ListTable (foreignkey, PositionInList, arraystringsConcatedWithSeperator)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map nested collections with NHibernate.

Put the string[] into its own class and map it as a composite element (then it doesn't need to be an entity).